# wordpress email checker on domain

Tags: php, themes, admin

I need a email verification when a users/admin logs into wp-admin. So it checks if the domain is @gmail.com and when is not i have functions is this possible?

I made it with id checker but is was not really user friendly and I only want @hostname.com the see a page

Comment: On every single log in? Why don't you check that during registration?

Comment: I want to hide the menus an add functions

Comment: I want to make a white label plugin in my child theme